# error[E0152]: found duplicate lang item `panic_impl`

Tags: ink, cargo-contract

Error message

```
 fn panic(info: &core::panic::PanicInfo) -> ! {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: the lang item is first defined in crate `std` (which `parity_scale_codec` depends on)
   = note: first definition in `std` loaded from /home/pinetree/PDAO/polkadot/target/ink/treasury/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/deps/libstd-466d0a37b6ee82d4.rmeta
   = note: second definition in the local crate (`ink_env`)
```

I want to import my own crate on ink! contract

my own crate(pdao-beacon-chain-common) is composed like this.

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug, PartialEq, Eq, Clone)]
#[cfg_attr(
    feature = "polkadot",
    derive(scale::Encode, scale::Decode, scale_info::TypeInfo)
)]
#[cfg_attr(feature = "cosmos", derive(schemars::JsonSchema))]
pub enum DeliverableMessage {
    FungibleTokenTransfer(FungibleTokenTransfer),
    NonFungibleTokenTransfer(NonFungibleTokenTransfer),
    Custom(Custom),
}
...
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug, PartialEq, Eq, Clone)]
#[cfg_attr(
    feature = "polkadot",
    derive(scale::Encode, scale::Decode, scale_info::TypeInfo)
)]
pub struct FungibleTokenTransfer {
    pub token_id: String,
    pub amount: u128,
    pub receiver_address: String,
    pub contract_sequence: u64,
}
```

(refer to https://use.ink/faq#what-are-the-scaleencode-and-scaledecode-traits, to import struct, they should inlcude "scale:Encode, scale:Decode")

and It's dependency is like this

```
[dependencies]
scale = { package = "parity-scale-codec", version = "3", default-features = false, features = ["derive"], optional = true }
scale-info = { version = "2.0.0", features = ["derive"], optional = true }
...
[features]
polkadot = ["scale", "scale-info"]
```

And, My Contract import that enum or struct,

```
...
    use pdao_beacon_chain_common::*;
...
```

And Contract dependency in Cargo.toml,

```
[dependencies]
ink_prelude = { version = "3", default-features = false }
ink_primitives = { version = "3", default-features = false }
ink_metadata = { version = "3", default-features = false, features = ["derive"], optional = true }
ink_env = { version = "3", default-features = false }
ink_storage = { version = "3", default-features = false }
ink_lang = { version = "3", default-features = false }

scale = { package = "parity-scale-codec", version = "3", default-features = false, features = ["derive"]}
scale-info = { version = "2", default-features = false, features = ["derive"], optional = true }

pdao-beacon-chain-common = { path="../../beacon-chain/common", version = "0.1.0", features = ["polkadot"] }
...
[features]
default = ["std"]
std = [
    "ink_prelude/std",
    "ink_metadata/std",
    "ink_env/std",
    "ink_storage/std",
    "ink_primitives/std",
    "scale/std",
    "scale-info/std",
]
```

It seems that parity-scale-codec has some dependecy problem. But I still don't know how to resolve it.

Do you have any Ideas..?

Comment: The problem occurs when I build a contract $cargo +nightly contract builld

Comment: you haven't included `pdao-beacon-chain-common/std` on `std = []`

Answer (score 1):

As stated by @Ganesh11 in the comments, you are likely missing `pdao-beacon-chain-common/std` in your `std` features.

I'm commenting the answer so that the question doesn't show up unanswered anymore.